# form validation

Tags: php, validation

To what degree of concern should I take when validating a form? What should be the general line to say enough?

Currently, I'm checking

- form token
- submit value = match internal hard code
- input name =  match internal hard code
- input vale = htmlspecialchar
- time delay will be (on some form) implemented in the future

I am a beginner on security, so please bear with me :)

Comment: Everything user-defined should be validated. The key is to never trust the user in any way.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex mentioned in the comment, if it crosses a security boundary, you need to be thoughtful and deliberate about handling the data, and understanding how an attacker might manipulate it before sending it to you.

This process is more generally known as application threat modeling.  It starts with defining the components of the application, the data flows between the components, where those data flows cross security boundaries, and what that data might contain.  Once you know this, you can then think about how an attacker might abuse the data before sending it across those boundaries, so you can best identify how to mitigate those potential vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Think about where the data might be used, as this should help define your validation.

You can get away with no validation at time of entry, however anything with special meaning when using a sink function should be discarded or encoded before usage. Validation at time of entry is useful if you want to allow your user to be able to correct any mistakes.

Sanitisation should be done as late as possible. For example, converting to HTML characters should be done on output rather than on input. The reason is that if you decide to use the data in a different context then you can convert them at this point straight from the user value (e.g. plain text, JSON, etc).

Never trust user input. Validate everything before use and try to think about the dangers of letting unexpected values submitted from your form - for example if a certain value was forged, or if the value will end up unencoded when it is used in a context with special meaning (e.g. SQL statement).